# Why do different Fourier transform conventions not make a diﬀerence in physical applications?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms, convention

In physics, we are used to at least two Fourier transform conventions. These are
$$\tilde{f}(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ikx}dx,\\
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(k)e^{-ikx}dk$$ or,
$$\tilde{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ikx}dx,\\
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(k)e^{-ikx}dk,$$

and we are often told that it is just a convention and it does not make a difference. But why is this so? The final result for $\tilde{f}(k)$ using them will differ by a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$. How can we then say that FT "conventions" don't make a difference? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I think about the Fourier transform a lot, and I like to use a convention that’s different than both the conventions you mentioned. The way I think of the Fourier transform is that it should be essentially an isometry of $L^2$ (possibly up to a constant), and it should have other nice properties like turning convolution into multiplication, and intertwining differentiation and multiplication by polynomials—which makes it useful for analyzing PDE.

I think the reason the constants and different conventions don’t cause us much fuss is because any convention we pick is going to be very useful in applications via those essential properties I mentioned, and translating between conventions is very simple. To switch between conventions we only need to do easy changes of variable in the integrals that define the Fourier transform.

It’s almost like using different bases to do linear algebra—there is no canonical choice of basis for a vector space, but different choices may be more useful in different contexts, and ultimately the choice does no real harm.

Comment: But in all the conventions I have seen, the product of the constant coefficients in front of the integrals is always $1/2\pi$. For example, in my first convention $1 \times \frac{1}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and in the second $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Is there something going on here?

Comment: I don’t think there is anything particularly deep about that. In the convention I use, $\hat f(\xi) = \int f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}dx$, and in the inverse Fourier transform you change the minus sign to a plus sign. The $2\pi$ ends up in the phase instead of in front of the integrals, and the formula is more uniform. An upside is that the Fourier transform in this convention is an isometry on the nose. The downside of this convention is that those $2\pi$s pile up if you’re differentiating many times. The motivation for using the Fourier transform at all is a deep, but ultimately different question